# Is there a way to manage path changes from local to cloud?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, pyspark, path

I regularly collaborate on large data analysis projects using PySpark. We developed that project working with local files. Now we want to deploy this project to Google Cloud.
As there are plenty of local paths, we have to change them to google cloud paths. Is there a good way to manage paths and ? This way should facilitate changes from local to cloud. 
I have tried adding each path as a variable. An example:

```
# [START download-data]

iris_data_filename = 'iris_data.csv'

iris_target_filename = 'iris_target.csv'

data_dir = 'gs://cloud-samples-data/ml-engine/iris'



# gsutil outputs everything to stderr so we need to divert it to stdout.

subprocess.check_call(['gsutil', 'cp', os.path.join(data_dir,

iris_data_filename),

iris_data_filename], stderr=sys.stdout)

subprocess.check_call(['gsutil', 'cp', os.path.join(data_dir,

iris_target_filename),

iris_target_filename], stderr=sys.stdout)

# [END download-data]





# [START load-into-pandas]

# Load data into pandas, then use `.values` to get NumPy arrays

iris_data = pd.read_csv(iris_data_filename).values

iris_target = pd.read_csv(iris_target_filename).values
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I would keep the base dir for local path in one variable, and the cloud storage path in another variable, so you can easily switch between them according to the environment.

```py
LOCAL_DIR = '/home/user/dir'
GCS_DIR = 'gs://my-bucket/dir'

# Choose the data_dir value according to your needs
data_dir = LOCAL_DIR if current_env == 'local' else GCS_DIR

# Continue working
iris_target_filename = 'iris_target.csv'

# Example of the full path
full_path = os.path.join(data_dir, iris_target_filename)
```

In addition, since pandas 0.24, if you have installed [gcsfs](https://gcsfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), you can use the GCS path directly without downloading the file first, which will make it easier to switch between environments.

Example:

```py
pd.read_csv('gs://cloud-samples-data/ml-engine/iris/iris_data.csv')
```

Comment: Thanks great example. But we have a lot of subdirectories (data_dir = 'gs://cloud-samples-data/ml-engine/iris', data_dir_2 = 'gs://cloud-samples-data/ml-engine/setosa', data_dir_3 = 'gs://cloud-samples-data/ml-engine2'...). Is this an apropiate way to handle them, or would be better to save all path in another configuration code?

Comment: If the base bucket for all of them is "gs://cloud-samples-data" you could use the same approach that I mentioned, and add the additional dir in the filename "ml-engine/setosa". The idea is to reduce the number of variables to change when switching between environments. Also, if there's a lot of paths and files, it might be cleaner and easier to read and modify if that information is in another configuration file